# GCP Foundation Toolkit: deploy a docker container in Cloud Run without using terraform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, workflow, google-cloud-build

I've deployed a simplified version of the Google Foundation toolkit into my GCP organization. It doesn't have all the bell and whistles, but it's a starting point (it is for educational purposes, actually)

In facts, I have one project "cloudbuild" where all the triggers for the cloud build are deployed. Each stage of my poor man's foundation has its onw git repo:

- Foundation (create the tf state the triggers)
- Environment (to create the environment folders and shared resources)
- Network (for DNS management only atm)
- Projects (to create app infra, one "project" per file)

PROBLEM:

A standard "project" is typically a dockerized app to be pulled from the registry and pushed into a Cloud Run. This is done by IaC pipeline and terraform (let's call it "app-infra"). This tf pipeline pull the given image from the registry and push into cloud run.

The DOCKERFILE and the source code of the app are in a different git repo (let's call it "app-code"). This repo has a cloudbuild file on its own to just build it and push into the registry. This because I don't want the dev team to be able to access the IaC code.

So, this is what happens:

- When the cloud architect push into app-infra, terraform apply is trigger and a new version of the docker image is pulled from the registry and pushed into Cloud Run.
- If a dev push into app-code, the new docker image is built and pushed into the registry, but since the deploy code is into the app-infra pipeline, it won't be deployed.

Did I completely mess my architecture design or there is a way to ensure proper security and segregation of duties on this scenario?